# How do I toggle play/pause with SoundJS?

Tags: javascript, soundjs

Im using SoundJS to build a psuedo MPC. I have the sound kit buttons programmed the way I want, but I cannot get the loops to work the way I want.

- I would like the user to click on "loop1" and it plays.
- If the user clicks "loop1" again, it should stop and resets.
- If the user clicks "loop2" while "loop1" is playing, then "loop1" stops and resets while "loop2" starts to play.

How could I master this problem. Warning, I'm a UI/UX designer at heart and still learning Javascript, so if you could give me a bit more detail when explaining, that would be great. Thanks!

Here's some of my code below, but to see it in action, check here: http://nowthatsgenius.com/clients/beatbox/

```
<body onload="init();">
    <section class="player-container">
        <article class="player-controls">
            <ul class="player-controls">
                <li class="player-controls-button" id="loop1" onclick="playSound(this)">Loop 1</li>
                <li class="player-controls-button" id="loop2" onclick="playSound(this)">Loop 2</li>
            </ul>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section class="mpc-container">
        <article class="mpc-title mpc-col">
            <span class="text">V1</span>
        </article>
        <article class="mpc-controls mpc-col">
            <ul class="mpc-controls-wrap">
                <li class="mpc-controls-row">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="mpc-controls-button" id="a1" onclick="playSound(this)"></li>
                        <li class="mpc-controls-button" id="a2" onclick="playSound(this)"></li>
                        <li class="mpc-controls-button" id="a3" onclick="playSound(this)"></li>
                        <li class="mpc-controls-button" id="a4" onclick="playSound(this)"></li>
                        <li class="mpc-controls-button" id="a5" onclick="playSound(this)"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="mpc-controls-button" id="a6" onclick="playSound(this)"></li>
                        <li class="mpc-controls-button" id="a7" onclick="playSound(this)"></li>
                        <li class="mpc-controls-button" id="a8" onclick="playSound(this)"></li>
                        <li class="mpc-controls-button" id="a9" onclick="playSound(this)"></li>
                        <li class="mpc-controls-button" id="a10" onclick="playSound(this)"></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </article>
    </section>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/soundjs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var preload;

        function init() {
            if (!createjs.Sound.initializeDefaultPlugins()) {
                document.getElementById("error").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("content").style.display = "none";
                return;
            }

            var assetsPath = "assets/";
        var sounds = [
                {id:"loop1", src:"loop1.mp3"},
                {id:"loop2", src:"loop2.mp3"},

            {id:"a1", src:"snare.wav"},
            {id:"a2", src:"kick1.wav"},
            {id:"a3", src:"clap1.wav"},
            {id:"a4", src:"closedhat.wav"},
            {id:"a5", src:"cymbal.wav"},
            {id:"a6", src:"kick2.wav"},
            {id:"a7", src:"clap2.wav"},
            {id:"a8", src:"openhat.wav"},
            {id:"a9", src:"voice1.wav"},
            {id:"a10", src:"voice2.wav"},
        ];

        $('.player-controls-button').attr("disabled",true);

        createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["mp3"];   
        createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", createjs.proxy(handleLoadComplete, this));
        createjs.Sound.registerSounds(sounds, assetsPath);
      }


        function playSound(target) {

            var instance = createjs.Sound.play(target.id, createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_NONE);

            $(".player-controls-button").click(function(event) {
                if (instance.playState == createjs.Sound.PLAY_SUCCEEDED) {
                    instance.stop();
                } 
                else {
                    instance.play(target.id, createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_NONE);
                }
            });

            console.log(instance.playState);
        }


    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify sounds after you've started playing them by assigning them to a variable. In this case, I've created variables `loop1` and `loop2`.

```
// Creating variables outside playSound() so they exist in the global scope.
var loop1 = null;
var loop2 = null;

function playSound(target) {
    if(loop1){  // If loop1 exists, stop it.
        loop1.stop();
    }
    if(loop2){  // If loop2 exists, stop it.
        loop2.stop();
    }


    if(target.id == "loop1"){
        // Assign value to var loop1
        loop1 = createjs.Sound.play(target.id, createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_NONE);
    }
    else if(target.id == "loop2"){
        // Assign value to var loop2
        loop2 = createjs.Sound.play(target.id, createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_NONE);
    }
    else{
        // Otherwise, create generic sound
        var instance = createjs.Sound.play(target.id, createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_NONE);
    }

    $(".player-controls-button").click(function(event) {
        if (instance.playState == createjs.Sound.PLAY_SUCCEEDED) {
            instance.stop();
        }else {
            instance.play(target.id, createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_NONE);
        }
    });

    console.log(instance.playState);
}
```

I recommend you separate your `playSound(target)` function for sound effects, and create a new one named `playLoop(target)` for your music loops, just to make it easier to read. But that's up to you.

**Version 2**

```
var loop1 = null;
var loop2 = null;
function playLoop(target){

    // If loop1 exists, stop it and delete it
    if(loop1){
        loop1.stop();
        loop1 = null;
    }else if(target.id == "loop1"){
        loop1 = createjs.Sound.play(target.id, createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_NONE);
    }

    // If loop2 exists, stop it and delete it
    if(loop2){
        loop2.stop();
        loop2 = null;
    }else if(target.id == "loop2"){
        loop2 = createjs.Sound.play(target.id, createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_NONE);
    }
}
```

When you assign createjs.Sound.play() to a variable, the variable becomes an `AbstractSoundInstance` object. You can modify it in many cool ways, [here's the documentation](http://createjs.com/Docs/SoundJS/classes/AbstractSoundInstance.html) if you want to learn what more you can do with these variables.

Comment: So I've made the changes and also separated the functions. The loops can stop each other, but the loops can't stop itself. If you play a loop and try to stop it, it just plays again. I've tried a bunch of different fixes, and couldn't get anywhere. What do you think it is? 

I've uploaded everything up to: http://nowthatsgenius.com/clients/beatbox/

All the code is on one page in the source.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean the loops can't stop itself? I thought that when you clicked on `loop1` you wanted it to reset and play again from the beginning. Do you want it to play on first click, then stop on the second click, then start over from 0 on the third click?

Comment: My apologies. Let me try to simplify: User clicks on loop1. Loop1 plays. While loop1 is playing, if user clicks on loop1, loop1 stops. While loop1 is playing, if user clicks on loop2, loop1 stops playing and loop2 starts to play. Both loops should never play at the same time. I don't want separate on/off buttons because when the User clicks on "loop1", the "loop1" button will blink, like a piano keyboard or MPC would.

Comment: Ok, I edited my response to include Version 2 below my original code. This `playLoop()` function will start a loop if it doesn't exist, or will stop it if it's already playing. It will also stop `loop1` if you click on `loop2`, and vice-versa.